# How do I change the background color of a conditional macro in eclipse?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, colors

How do I change the background color of a conditional macro in eclipse? I am using the C/C++ version of Eclipse so I would assume it would be associated with a mysterious preprocessor background color setting.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Inactive Code Highlight

Duh! ;-)